# Adding dollar sign before each string in array?

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, preg-match, substr

I have this string: `$str = "(he+is+genius*2)/clever";` which looks like this in array;

```
Array ( 
  [0] => ( 
  [1] => he 
  [2] => + 
  [3] => is 
  [4] => + 
  [5] => genius 
  [6] => ) 
  [7] => * 
  [8] => and 
  [9] => / 
  [10] => clever )
```

What I want to do is placing dollar sign $ before each string present in `$str` but ignoring non-alphanumeric and numbers.
 At the end i want to have something which looks like this;

```
$newstr = "($he+$is+$genius*2)/$clever";
```

Comment: ...which you then want to `eval`, I guess? No, that's not genius. Rather look at a safe expression engine instead of `eval`: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/index.html

Comment: What is eval? I dont want to use eval, i want to have that format and display it.

Comment: Hmm, okay. That's unusual, but not so bad then. Just remember the above whenever you feel the urge to `eval`... ;)

Comment: How do you get the array from the given string?

Comment: Where did `and` go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each value, check if the first char (or the whole value) is made of characters with `ctype_alpha`, then prepend with `$` :

```
// $arr is your array as defined in your question
foreach ($arr as &$val) {
 //OR if (ctype_alpha($val[0])) { 
 if (ctype_alpha($val)) { // if you have other qualifying conditions add them here
   $val = '$' . $val;
 }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Output :

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "$he"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "+"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "$is"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "+"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "$genius"
  ...
}
```

Second solution, checking if it has a char at any position :

```
foreach ($arr as &$val) {
  $tmp = str_split($val); 
  foreach ($tmp as $char) {
    if (ctype_alpha($char)) {
      $val = '$' . $val;
      break;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: This is working, but forexample if string is (he2+is+genius*2)/clever"; It wont put dollar sign in he2, I just dont want to put dollar sign in number which is standalone like 2 in a string. Unless the number is part of string like he2.

Comment: Try with `if (ctype_alpha($val[0])) { `. As I said in the answer, it will check the first character only. Or you want to check if the value contains a char at any position, even in the middle ?

Comment: @user2579351 I edited my answer and added a second solution for that. It breaks each values into characters, and if any character is a letter, it prepend $

Comment: Sorry Clement, is it possible to prevent dollar sign to be added to a certain strings, for example if there is a word she, who or they  in a $arr than dollar sign should not be added to these strings

Comment: @user2579351 I'm not your personal helper. ;) There is a lot of people on Stack Overflow that would be glad to help you. If you have another question, just ask a new one properly and explain your new problem, using comments to ask questions is bad. You will get more good and quick help that way ! :) (If needed, you can add a link to this question in your new question, so it helps people to understand the context)

Comment: Oh k I get you, this is my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870734/prevent-dollar-sign-to-be-added-from-certain-strings

Answer (score 0):

Just map the array using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and check if their values are string or not with [`ctype_alpha`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php), concatenating the `$` to it.

```
$array = array ( 
0 => "(",
1 => "he",
2 => "+",
3 => "is",
4 => "+",
5 => "genius",
6 => ")",
7 => "*",
8 => "and",
9 => "/", 
10 => "clever"
);

$strA = array_map (function($a) {
    if (ctype_alpha($a)) // if only alphabetic characters return it with dollar sign
        return "$".$a;
    return $a; // else return normal
}, $array );

echo implode("",$strA); // ($he+$is+$genius)*$and/$clever
```