# Prevent dollar sign to be added from certain strings

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, preg-match, substr

I have this this array;

```
Array ( 
       [0] => ( 
       [1] => he 
       [2] => + 
       [3] => is 
       [4] => + 
       [5] => genius 
       [6] => ) 
       [7] => * 
       [8] => and 
       [9] => / 
       [10] => clever )
```

It was possibe to put dollar sign before each alphanumeric string in array, the link is here :
[Adding dollar sign before each string in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868547/adding-dollar-sign-before-each-string-in-array)

Now, Is it possible to prevent dollar sign to be added to a certain strings, for example if there is a word she, who or they in array than dollar sign should not be added to these strings?

Comment: only `she` `who` or `they`? Or are there more words?

Comment: there are more words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going off of your old code, I amended it:

```
$noappend = array("she","who","they"); // add more

// $arr is your array as defined in your question
foreach ($arr as &$val) {
  //OR if (ctype_alpha($val[0])) { 
  if (ctype_alpha($val) && !in_array($val, $noappend)) {
    $val = '$' . $val;
  }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: am using second solution, that was first one, foreach ($arr as &$val) {
  $tmp = str_split($val); 
  foreach ($tmp as $char) {
    if (ctype_alpha($char)) {
      $val = '$' . $val;
      break;
    }
  } 
}

Comment: Why are you using `ctype_alpha`? And also instead of two nested `if` statements you should use an `AND` or `&&`

Comment: @user2579351 using a foreach loop is very similar to `array_map` and should run faster as well.

Comment: Thanks James and Dan!

Comment: I used his older code, was just amending it, but you're correct Dan, I'll amend now.

Answer (score 2):

Define your words in an array:
`$no_dollar_sign = array('she', 'who', 'they');`

Loop through your array and add the dollar sign to strings that are not in the `$no_dollar_sign` array, using [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
foreach($array as $key => $item){
    if(!in_array($item, $no_dollar_sign)){
        $array[$key] = '$'.$item;
    }
}
```

The new values will be in `$array` with no change to the blocked words.

If your "no dollar sign" list is significantly larger and it is not reasonable to create/manage your own list then you should define very clearly what the rules are for why something should or should not be concatenated with a `$` and potentially use regex.